# file does not upload in code-igniter using post method

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have to upload a file in CodeIgniter using form with `POST` method. However, I have to use Codeigniter's file uploading technique in my controller. For doing that, I have written following peice of code but it does not upload the file and display error that *No File was chosen*. please tell what can be issue?

**Code:**

```
/* HTML FORM INSIDE VIEW */
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/transferdata/uploadfile';?>" method="post" id="uploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" style="display: none;" onchange="document.getElementById('submitfile').click();" />
    <a class="toolbar" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('userfile').click();">
        <span title="Upload" class="icon-32-upload"></span>
        Upload
    </a>
    <input type="submit" name="submitfile" id="submitfile" style="display: none;" />
</form> 


/* CODE-IGNITER CONTROLLER at index.php/transferdata/uploadfile */
$config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx'; 
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($_POST["userfile"])) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_response',$this->upload->display_errors());
    redirect(base_url()."index.php/transferdata"); 
    return;
}

$file_details = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$file_path = $file_details['upload_data']['full_path'];
```

Comment: use this in your form tag first enctype="multipart/form-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you upload any file you must have set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form
So change your form tag to:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/transferdata/uploadfile';?>" method="post" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also in codeigniter controller change your do_upload method as below:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("userfile")) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Iinsert below code in your form tag : `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

And change here  `$this->upload->do_upload("userfile");`